# Reading list of data from firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to request you to please tell me how to read the data :
i)Order Details from every unique id node
ii)Order Items from every unique id node.

please someone tell me . I cannot figure out a way. please !!!

please see the image that I have uploaded.[image]

Comment: Without seeing what you've already tried, it is unlikely that we'll do a better job explaining it than the existing [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) already do. I recommend checking those out, and posting back with more [a minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file and not as a picture. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).